# How to reserve a set of primary key identifiers for preloading bootstrap data

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, hbm2ddl

We would like to reserve a set of primary key identifiers for all tables (e.g. 1-1000) so that we can bootstrap the system with pre-loaded system data.

All our JPA entity classes have the following definition for the primary key.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer id;
```

is there a way to tell the database that increments should start happening from 1000 (i.e. customer specific data will start from 1000 onwards). We support (`h2, mysql, postgres`) in our environment and I would prefer a solution which can be driven via JPA and reverse engineering DDL tools from Hibernate.

Let me know if this is the correct approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `TABLE` strategy instead of `IDENTITY`. From the Hibernate book:

> Much like Hibernate’s `hilo` strategy, `TABLE`
>   relies on a database table that holds the last generated
>   integer primary key value, and each
>   generator is mapped to one row in this table.
>   Each row has two columns: `pkColumnName`
>   and `valueColumnName`. The `pkColumnValue` assigns each row to a particular generator,
>   and the value column holds the last
>   retrieved primary key. The persistence provider
>   allocates up to `allocationSize` integers
>   in each turn.

Here is [an example](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/jpa/howto/id-generation.html#table) with more explanation. And a more complex [example for setting the initial value](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/SetInitialValueOfTableGenerator.htm).

You could also try using a custom sequence generator, defined in your `orm.xml`, like this:

```
<sequence-generator name="mySequenceGenerator"
  sequence-name="MY_SEQUENCE"
  initial-value="123"
  allocation-size="20"/>
```

> This declares that a database sequence named `MY_SEQUENCE` with an initial value
>   of 123 can be used as a source for database identifier generation, and that the persistence
>   engine should obtain 20 values every time it needs identifiers. (Note,
>   though, that Hibernate Annotations, at the time of writing, ignores the `initialValue` setting.)
>
> To apply this identifier generator for a particular entity, use its name:

```
@Entity
class name MyEntity {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "mySequenceGenerator")
  String id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If everything else fails, you can always write your own custom ID generator and use it in your DAO's `create(Entity entity)` method. The ID sequence table could be something like

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| sequence_name | initial_value | current_value | increment |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|           foo |          1001 |          2000 |       100 |
```

This could mean that IDs for table `foo` start at 1001 and are incremented by 100 (so you don't have to call DB for each new table insert).

That's what we're using without much problems.